# Binary tree traversal with level

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

is there any kind of way to traverse the tree, which would allow me to print out the binary tree WITH the level of each node ? So let's say I have this tree:

```
   10
   /\
  5  15
 /    /\
2    12 16
```

And the output (in preorder for example) would be:

node (level)

10 (0), 5 (1), 2 (2), 15 (1), 12 (2), 16 (2)

the most ideal way would be with binary way:

10 ([]), 5 ([1]), 2 ([11]), 15 ([0]), 12 ([01]), 16 ([00])

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: well where is the code you used for your binary tree? and what is the issue is it not pinting the level or are you looking for a binary trre implementation which when printing also prints the level?

Comment: I have tried preorder, but I didn't know how to do this without actually storing the information of the node level in the node.

Comment: show your code then for the binary tree

Comment: I am implementing hash binary tree in the file. We hash the data and traverse the tree to the point we reach external node and then save it there. I am only allowed to store children and father of the node in the node's class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely possible. It looks like you want to traverse the tree in depth first order which makes things nice and simple.

The algorithm will look something like this (in pseudocode since no code provided for reference):

```
void traverse(node, depth) {
  print(node.value, depth);
  depth++;
  traverse(node.leftChild, depth);
  traverse(node.rightChild, depth);
  depth--;
}
```

So you just call that method passing in the root node of the tree and the initial depth (0).

Comment: Is it possible to do this without recursion ?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, but the code will be a lot longer and much harder to understand. If you don't have a specific requirement NOT to use recursion then recursion is the generally accepted way of traversing trees.

Comment: I do have specific requirement NOT to use recursion as I work with huge amount of data of which the tree is stored in the memory and data is stored in the blocks in file.dat . At this point I'm trying to save the tree from the memory to the .txt or a binary file. I am told recursion slows things down big time.

Comment: The problem with recursion (in very basic terms) is that each time you call a method it's added to the call stack so that you can return to the calling method when it's finished executing. With recursion you are calling the same method many times so you are filling up the heap with these methods. So it's not necessarily a speed issue, but a memory issue (which could result in speed issues). There is almost always an iterative approach to a recursive algorithm, but the trade off is that it's not as clear to other developers so maintainability may suffer.

Comment: So to answer the question, I'm presuming you already have a iterative implementation and that it's the depth issue you are stuck on, just follow the gist of the algorithm above. Increment depth as you go down a level, decrement as you go back up.

Comment: All right, thanks, I'll do my best.

Comment: No problem, hope it goes ok. If you get stuck at a particular issue post another question with the code that is causing the problem and I'll be happy to take a look.